# undefined control sequence in an included file

Tags: texstudio, include, undefined

I am using TeXstudio to handle a long document  organized around a main document and a series of included chapters that are separate .tex files (of course the chapter files begin with `\chapter` and do not have a `\begin{document}`. I have been working for the very same files for long time now; generally I can compile the document from the main document window or from the chapter window, the result is the same: I get my nice pdf file.
In the last hours, if I compile from the chapter window I get a series of errors starting with `undefined control sequence \chapter` and `missing \begin{document} \chapter{`
However, if I compile from the main document, everything goes well and I even have the variations introduced in the chapter.
This problem occurs only with one chapter, not with the rest that are written in the same way.

Comment: What is the class of your main file?

Comment: You can't compile the separate chapters if they don't have a `\documentclass`. If you did this previously, you may have clicked a button to compile a project, but not the separate chapter file.

Comment: actually, I have been working for years with a main document and separate files without preamble. As a matter of fact, if I put `\documentclass` in a chapter I get an error message. Unless for "project" you mean what I call "main document". My main flie class is scrbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TexStudio tries to auto detect your main document, but this can sometimes fail. It won't work if you main document is not open for example. You can add

```
% !TeX root = root-filename
```

to your included file to explicitly specify the main document. Replace `root-filename` with the file name of your main document, e.g. `./main.tex`. If your included files are in a subfolder, use `../main.tex` to reference the parent folder.

See section `4.1.1` in the [user manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33b) for more information.

Comment: Magic comment and magic answer! Thank you